# script output from ansible playbook differs from regular script output

Tags: ansible

**playbook**

```
---
- name: Transfer and execute a script.
  hosts: all
  tasks:

 - name: Transfer the script
   copy: src=test1.sh dest=/home/bhreddy mode=0777

 - name: Execute the script
   command: sh /home/bhreddy/test1.sh
   register: validate1

 - name: run cmd
   shell: echo "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
   register: validate


 - name: Write results to logfile
   blockinfile:
     create: yes
     path: "/var/log/ansible/log"
     insertafter: BOF
     block: "{{ validate.stdout }} | {{ validate.stderr }}"
     block: "{{ validate1.stdout }} | {{ validate1.stderr }}"
     marker: "# {{ inventory_hostname }} {mark}"
   delegate_to: localhost
```

**script**

```
root@bhreddy-VirtualBox:/home/bhreddy# cat test1.sh 
#!/bin/bash
pass="password"
echo  $pass | sudo -S su -c "fdisk -l"
```

If I run the above playbook, the output is like below:

```
root@bhreddy-VirtualBox:~# cat /var/log/ansible/log 
# 192.168.56.102 BEGIN
Disk /dev/sda: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x37eaf900

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 20969471 20967424  10G 83 Linux | [sudo] password for bhreddy: 
# 192.168.56.102 ENDroot@bhreddy-VirtualBox:~#
```

If I run my shell script directly the output is like below:

```
root@bhreddy-VirtualBox:/home/bhreddy# ./test1.sh 
Disk /dev/sda: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x37eaf900

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 20969471 20967424  10G 83 Linux
```

I am not sure why these extra words added when I execute playbook. **"| [sudo] password for bhreddy:"**

please suggest how to have same output like when I execute script directly.

Answer (score 1):

You see `| [sudo] password for bhreddy:` because you instructed Ansible to print a pipe character followed by the `stderr` of the `Execute the script` task in the following line:

```
block: "{{ validate1.stdout }} | {{ validate1.stderr }}"
```

And stderr contains a password prompt from `sudo` command, because you execute your script as user `bhreddy` (that's why it is asking for `bhreddy`'s password).

In your shell example, however, you were executing `sudo` as `root` (as in the posted shell prompt `root@bhreddy-VirtualBox`) and this does not require inputting the password.

---

The output is exactly the same in both cases, and all you need to do is to use only the stdout:

```
block: "{{ validate1.stdout }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

> [sudo] password for bhreddy:

comes from stderr of the script.

I suggest you a total different approach because you don't need this tasks wrapping this script to do a fdisk as root.

You replace the "*Transfer the script*" and "*Execute the script*" with

```
- name: list the partition
  command: /usr/sbin/fdisk
  become: true # to become root
  register: validate1
```

Comment: `|` comes from this template `"{{ validate1.stdout }} | {{ validate1.stderr }}"`